# Java Hangman - Error Checking

Tags: java, error-handling, indexof

For my hangman game I would like to have a bunch of error messages to check for things like more than one letter entered, guessing the same letter twice, etc. My full code so far:

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.util.Random;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.UIManager;
    import javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource;

    public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        public MainFrame() {
            initComponents();
        }
        //declare variables
        static String secretWord = "";
        double result = 0;
        StringBuilder mainWord = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder xletters = new StringBuilder(); // letters guessed
        String[] words = {"technology", "computer", "camera", "graphic", "digital", "media", "technician",
            "photography", "troubleshoot", "pixels", "application", "download"};
        Random r = new Random();
        int randValue = r.nextInt(12);
        String guessWord = words[randValue];
        int errors = 0;
        public static int wins = 0, losses = 0;
        String foundWord = null;
        private void GuessButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)         {                                            
            String strGuess = GuessText.getText(); //user input           
            String letter = strGuess;
            xletters.append(strGuess.toUpperCase());
            String GuessedLetters = xletters.toString();

            try {
    //replace underscores with letters as they are guessed
                do {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                        secretWord = secretWord + letter.charAt(0);
                        foundWord = words[randValue].replaceAll("[^" + secretWord + "]", "_ ");
                        //if user entered more than one letter
                        if (strGuess.length() > 1) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Only one letter at a time!");
                            xletters.append("");
                            GuessedLetters = null;
                            GuessText.setText(null);
                            GuessText.requestFocusInWindow();
                        } //if letter isn't in word
                        else if (guessWord.indexOf(strGuess) == -1) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, that wasn't in the word.");
                            errors++;
                            if (errors == 1) {
                                Hangman0.setVisible(false);
                            }
                            if (errors == 2) {
                                Hangman1.setVisible(false);
                            }
                            if (errors == 3) {
                                Hangman2.setVisible(false);
                            }
                            if (errors == 4) {
                                Hangman3.setVisible(false);
                            }
                            if (errors == 5) {
                                Hangman4.setVisible(false);
                            }
                            if (errors == 6) {
                                Hangman5.setVisible(false);
                            }
                            if (errors == 7) {
                                Hangman6.setVisible(false);
                            }
                            if (errors == 8) {
                                Hangman7.setVisible(false);
                            }
                            if (errors == 9) {
                                Hangman8.setVisible(false);
                            }
                            if (errors == 10) {
                                Hangman9.setVisible(false);
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You lost! The word was: " + guessWord);
                                losses++;
                                DirectionsFrame DFrame = new DirectionsFrame();
                                DFrame.setVisible(true);
                                setVisible(false);
                                MainFrame MFrame = new MainFrame();
                                MFrame.dispose();
                                xletters.delete(0, 100);
                                secretWord = "";
                                foundWord = null;
                                strGuess = null;
                                String strLosses = Integer.toString(losses);
                                String strWin = Integer.toString(wins);
                                DirectionsFrame.WinsLabel.setText(strWin);
                                DirectionsFrame.LossesLabel.setText(strLosses);
                            }
                }
            }
                    WordLabel.setText(foundWord.toUpperCase());
                    GuessedLabel.setText(GuessedLetters);
                    GuessText.setText(null);
                    GuessText.requestFocusInWindow();
                } while (foundWord == null);
                if (foundWord.equalsIgnoreCase(guessWord)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Yay!");
                    wins++;
                    DirectionsFrame DFrame = new DirectionsFrame();
                    DFrame.setVisible(true);
                    setVisible(false);
                    MainFrame MFrame = new MainFrame();
                    MFrame.dispose();
                    xletters.delete(0, 100);
                    secretWord = "";
                    foundWord = null;
                    String strWin = Integer.toString(wins);
                    String strLosses = Integer.toString(losses);
                    DirectionsFrame.WinsLabel.setText(strWin);
                    DirectionsFrame.LossesLabel.setText(strLosses);
                }
            } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a letter.");
                GuessedLabel.setText(GuessedLetters);
                GuessText.setText(null);
                GuessText.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        }                                           


        private void GetButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            //print out underscores to begin game
            for (int i = 0; i < guessWord.length(); i++) {
                mainWord.append("_ ");
            }
            String SetMain = mainWord.toString();
            mainWord.append(secretWord);
            WordLabel.setText(SetMain);
            GuessButton.setEnabled(true);
            GetButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

The one I'm having the most trouble with is the checking if the user entered the same letter twice. So you can only guess one letter in the alphabet once. Also, the code where it checks if the user entered more than one letter has a bug I believe, because where I want it to not add those letters to the guessed letters box, it adds in anyways. (i.e. user guesses "hf" and in the guessed letters goes "hf", where it should just be nothing)

I feel the answer lies in the method indexOf(), but I'm not entirely sure of what the if condition would say...

I'm using Netbeans IDE 7.2 to compile my code. Please help! Thanks.

Comment: BTW : `Hangman0`...`Hangman9` could be changed to `Hangman[errors]`. Just a thought.

Comment: ... and why don't you just have 26 buttons labelled `A` to `Z` and let the user press them (`button.setEnabled(false);`) instead of using a text box?

Comment: @YanickRochon those are names of the labels that have the hangman pictures. I was going to do that to begin with but I thought it would be difficult. How would I set the button to equal the letter?

Comment: look at the button's [action command](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setActionCommand%28%29)

Comment: @YanickRochon, so for instance i have a button called "A". then when that button is clicked.....then what? In other words, how would I set it to equal the letter a, and then would i have to copy my for loop into each of the letters?

Comment: if you set the same action listener for every of these buttons, and each button has their action command set to a given letter (for example "A"), then inside the `actionPerformed` method you may get which button was pressed using [`evt.getActionComment()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html#getActionCommand%28%29) (ex: which would return the string "A" if that button is pressed) and you should be able to retrieve the given `JButton` with `(JButton) evt.getSource()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a situation where you want to know if something has already been used, a `Set` comes to hand. For example, used letters in a hangman game, you'd have `Set<String>` collection :

```
Set<String> lettersUsed = new HashSet<String>();
```

If you want to know if something has already been chosen :

```
String inputLetter = "Z";  // test for the letter Z

if (!lettersUsed.contains(inputLetter)) {
    lettersUsed.add(inputLetter);

    // process letter in word
} else {
    // letter has already been used!
}
```

If you want to allow only a specific set of letters, already initially set :

```
if (lettersAllowed.contains(inputLetter)) {
   lettersAllowed.remove(inputLetter);

   // process letter in word
} else {
   // letter is not allowed (anymore)
}
```

Comment: i tried using `if (guessedLetters.contains(strGuess))` but it didn't work. guessedLetters is the list of letters guessed and strGuess is their input

Comment: how would i use the `lettersUsed` to collect the letters the user guessed?

Comment: @JavaProdigy, can you clarify if the user may specify more than one letter per input? I'm assuming the user can enter only one letter at a time right now.

Comment: they can guess only one at a time, now i set it to a-z buttons instead

Answer (score 0):

For seeing if they've already guessed something, you could have a String guesses that is empty at first, and when they make a guess, you could add that letter to the String:

```
String guesses = "";
...
guesses+= letter;
```

It looks like you're doing something similar already, but be sure to just append the letter, not create a new String for it. That way, you can check each time if your guesses String already contains the newly guessed letter (if(guesses.contains(letter)).

Also, I'm not sure why you have a for loop with only one iteration, but in the multi-letter case, you could try breaking out of the loop, or continuing if you fe

Answer (score 0):

what i would to for your letter checking is: make a List with used letters.
every time the player try's a letter you check with a for loop if that letter is in your list.
if it is not you add it to the list.
this is an example:

```
List<String> usedletters = new List<String>(26);

boolean checkLetterUsed(String input){
    boolean tempvariable = false;
    for(String letter: usedletters){
        if(letter==input){
            tempvariable = true;
        }
    }
    if(tempvariable){
        return true;
    }else{
        usedletters.add(input);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you explain the for loop used there? it's different from what im used to. also im using a StringBuilder to add the guessed letters to the jLabel, does that make a difference?

Comment: the for loop say: for every string you find in the list usedletters loop, and give the current string the variable letter. and it does't matter if you use a string or a string builder. as long as you can compare it.